# Filet out date based data in mongodb

Tags: python, mongodb

I am working on a Python script where I am querying a collection and getting the data where it is not empty.

```
db.open_sr.find({"bugs": {"$ne": {}, "$exists": true}})
>>    {
  _id: ObjectId("6450cbe0e23d288fb62aefdf"),
  bugs: {
    '2022-03-02T09:27:10': 'CSCdi21568'
  }
}
{
  _id: ObjectId("6450cbe0e23d288fb62aefe0"),
  bugs: {
    '2022-05-11T21:26:35': 'CSCsh83148',
    '2022-05-11T21:26:42': 'CSCsh83148'
  }
}
```

But Now Here I want to add one more query and want the data where age is less then 180 days of the given timestamp with the id. How can I add one more query here to get the required data.

Comment: Use MQL `$and` operator to combine query and comparison operator to compare Time
https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/query/and/

Comment: Having a date value a key looks like a very bad design. You should review it. How would you put an index on such field, if desired?

Comment: Storing timestamp as a key. This is how they are storing bugs and at what time it created.